# PPTP VPN and Untangle Device

Tags: vpn, pptp

I have a question regarding PPTP VPN with encryption. I work in an office that uses this untangle device (http://www.untangle.com/).  It is a firewall, that also has web blocking, virus blocking, web monitoring and all that other fun stuff, its a pretty cool device.  So here comes the question, when using PPTP VPN (the PPTP VPN is a network that's not the works) with encryption at the office would the untangles device be able to monitor the network traffic for the user using the PPTP VPN with encryption?

the PPTP VPN setup using a DD-WRT router with required encryption.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

It can't get inside the encrypted wrapper, but it might block it altogether.

Comment: It works just fine, I am able to connect.  Just wanted to see if it can track the websites I visit.

Comment: I'm sorry, it should say make sure it CANT* track my web activity.

Comment: It can't - BUT you have to make sure that DNS queries go over the VPN as well, otherwise that leaks information about the names of sites you visit. It would be good to become familiar with Wireshark on your computer, so you can see exactly what is being sent in the clear.

Comment: How can I make sure the DNS queries go over the VPN?

Comment: So to add a little more information here.  I did a "nslookup server" inside the command prompt on Win 7 machine.  What comes up is this: "Server: DD-WRT name"
"Address: the ip address of the router"
"*** DD-wrt server name cant find the server: Query refused"

Not 100% sure if this means all DNS queries are going through there or not.